# SparkR out of memory error

Tags: java, r, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, sparkr

I have a 2 node test cluster on AWS with spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7 installed.

This is the code I'm using to launch the cluster.

```
./spark-ec2 -k blah -i blah.pem -r us-west-1 -s 1 -t r3.2xlarge launch --copy-aws-credentials blah
```

Viewing port 8080 shows 58.8GB(0.0 B Used) of memory after running these two lines in rstudio.

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME="/root/spark")

library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib")))
```

When I run this line and refresh the page on port 8080 the memory usage changes to 58.8 GB (53.8 GB Used).

```
sparkR.session(master = "spark://[ip]:7077",

               sparkHome = '/root/spark',

               enableHiveSupport = FALSE)
```

When I try to create a spark data frame from a data frame which should consume 0.04857268 GB of memory I get this error:

```
acquisition <- as.DataFrame(orig)

17/11/04 14:27:23 WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 0 contains a task of very large size (166360 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.
Exception in thread "dispatcher-event-loop-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I tried adding this but get the same error.

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx2048m")
install.packages("rJava")
library(rJava)
```

I'm stuck. I've spent three weekends googling this issue and can't figure it out.

Thanks.